# remote connection to mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, remote-access

i have two machine
PC#1 with db `mysql` and `appache` and PC#2 with a c# form try to connect to this db

here is my connection string used in PC#2: `SERVER=My_public_ip;DATABASE = my_test; UID = root; PASSWORD = xxxx;"`

when i try to connect locally from PC#1 it work good:

`SERVER=localhost;DATABASE = my_test; UID = root; PASSWORD = xxxx;"`

when i try

i did make my root user remote enabled like that:

`GRANT ALL ON *.* to '%'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

and all i get is an Event viewer: `unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL host`

[image]

Comment: What Are You Asking ???

Answer (score 0):

If both MySql installation are similar (no port changes etc.) then you might want to check connection restriction to the port that MySQL is listening to (usually 3306) on the remote machine. A firewall or something of that sort may be preventing access.

Also if I may ask, have you used any other tool(like MySQL WorkBench or similar) to connect to the MySQL on the remote machine, from the machine which is running your c# form.

That may give you an idea as to whether it access restrictions.

Lastly, i suggest you specify the port in the connection string.

"Data Source =SomeName; Database=SomeDb; User Id=SomeUserId; Password=SomePassword; Port=3306;"

Comment: i didn't use any other tools but i will try it, i add PORT=3306; but still the same, so how to change the firewall settings to allow that connection?

Comment: What operating systems are you using on both PCs?